# My bot keeps saying "User not found" though the user is on my server

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

this is my code. I been only able to mute some bots and myself and a few users but not all, I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong but any help would be appreciated :)

```
else if (isValidCommand(message, 'mute')) {
    message.delete()
    if (!message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS'])){
      message.channel.send("You don't have permission to use this command.");
    }
    else {
      let memberId = message.content.substring(message.content.indexOf(' ') + 1);
      let member = message.guild.members.cache.get(memberId);
      if (member) {
        if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS']) && !message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
          message.channel.send("You cannot mute that person!");
        }
        else {
          let mutedRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('956241047753744414');
          if (mutedRole) {
            member.roles.add(mutedRole);
            message.channel.send("User was muted.");
          }
          else {
            message.channel.send("Muted role not found.");
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        message.channel.send("Member not found.");
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the user is offline? Maybe the guild member count is large enough not for the bot to load all of the members at once? Well, then there are two things I must then tell.

1. Use intents that allow your bot to cache guild members
2. Instead of using `cache.get` on member list, use `fetch` to fetch a uncached member. (more info at djs guide: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch )